# NiFi 1.5.0 : GenerateTableFetch order results

Tags: apache-nifi

Is it possible getting a dataset from a Database and order them? 
I have a very big table (72milion of rows) and I need to get them in a parallel way (as the GenerateTableFetch does) but ordered by a column, in my case `"url"` ?

[image: GenerateTableFetch setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a Maximum-value Column, then the queries will be ordered on that column (for incremental fetching). You may be able to try adding your ORDER BY clause to the "Additional WHERE clause" section.

As of NiFi 1.7.0 (not yet released at the time of this writing) you can specify arbitrary queries in QueryDatabaseTable (via [NIFI-1706](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1706)), please feel free to write a corresponding Jira for GenerateTableFetch. I'm not sure about the logistics of adding it to GTF, but if it works for QDT, I don't see why we can't add it to GTF.